# Trying to understand how describe_instances() work

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Trying to understand how describe_instances() work
Here is a code which gives me instances ids of all the instances I have currently 3 so 3 instance id I get

```
    import boto3 
    from pprint import pprint

    ec2=boto3.client('ec2') 
    response=ec2.describe_instances()
    instancelist = [] 
   for reservation in (response["Reservations"]):
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            instancelist.append(instance["InstanceId"]) print (instancelist)
```

gives me output

> ['i-03e7f6391a0f523ee', 'i-0e12c8dad5fb6d8c5', 'i-002adcd0913e4d673']

But if I write following

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
response=ec2.describe_instances()
for x in response:
    print (x)
    print ("in for loop")
```

I just get following output

```
Reservations
in for loop
ResponseMetadata
in for loop
```

What I was expecting was instance id’s of instance. 
Now I wrote following

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
response=ec2.describe_instances()

print (response["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"])
print (response["Reservations"][1]["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"])
print (response["Reservations"][1]["Instances"][1]["InstanceId"])
```

I get output

> i-03e7f6391a0f523ee i-0e12c8dad5fb6d8c5 i-002adcd0913e4d673

the above print statement does not work if written as below

```
print (response["Reservations"][2]["Instances"][0]["InstanceId"])
```

It gives error

```
    print (response["Reservations"][2]["Instances"][1]["InstanceId"])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I am not able to understand is how are the values being returned by describe_instances method in the statement

```
response=ec2.describe_instances()
```

Why the above for loop where I used x does not give output. I read the documentation here 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances
and as far as  I understand ec2.describe_instances() is returning a dictionary() 
Contains the output of DescribeInstances.
•   Reservations (list) --
Zero or more reservations. So with that understanding I thought I should be able to iterate over list members via

```
response["Reservations"][0]
response["Reservations"][1]
response["Reservations"][2]
```

But this is giving me error

```
print(response["Reservations"][2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am unable to understand the response which is coming via ec2.describe_instances()

Output of print (response) as asked in below answer

```
    {'Reservations': [

    {'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-d783a9b8', 

    'InstanceId': 'i-03e7f6391a0f523ee', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'datastructutre key', 

    'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 25, 10, 3, 53, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 

    'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-south-1a', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 

    'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': 

    '172.31.20.16', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': '', 'State': {'Code': 80, 'Name': 

    'stopped'}, 'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2018-08-25 10:07:17 GMT)', 'SubnetId': 

    'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': 

    [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 4, 28, 52, 

    tzinfo=tzutc()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-

    09716d3308f44c63f'}}], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 

    'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Attachment': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 

    8, 1, 4, 28, 52, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-08d060230b617ca70', 

    'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached'}, 'Description': '', 

    'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 'GroupId': 'sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58'}, {'GroupName': 

    'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': '02:5a:17:52:69:a6', 

    'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-0146aab6d9503bf47', 'OwnerId': '11000101010', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-

    172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.20.16', 

    'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-

    1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.20.16'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 

    'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60'}], 'RootDeviceName': 

    '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 

    'GroupId': 'sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58'}, {'GroupName': 'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 

    'SourceDestCheck': True, 'StateReason': {'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown', 'Message': 

    'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'}, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 

    'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}}], 'OwnerId': '11000101010', 'ReservationId': 

    'r-0571937a9ea83fac4'}, 

  {'Groups': [], 'Instances': [

{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19', 'InstanceId': 'i-0e12c8dad5fb6d8c5', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'datastructutre key', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 25, 10, 3, 53, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-south-1a', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-28-39.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.28.39', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': '', 'State': {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'}, 'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2018-08-25 10:07:17 GMT)', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 21, 33, 44, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-01d5ce67c9f1b081e'}}], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Attachment': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 21, 33, 44, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-0cbdea888315049ae',  'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached'}, 'Description': '',  'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': '02:f4:b8:bd:84:26', 'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-0d99a7669a1e4b9db', 'OwnerId': '11000101010', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-28-39.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.28.39', 'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-28-39.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.28.39'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60'}], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'StateReason': {'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown', 'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'}, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}}, 

{'AmiLaunchIndex': 1, 'ImageId': 'ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19', 'InstanceId': 'i-002adcd0913e4d673', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'datastructutre key', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime (2018, 8, 25, 10, 3, 53, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-south-1a', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-30-108.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.30.108', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': '', 'State': {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'}, 'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2018-08-25 10:07:17 GMT)', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 21, 33, 44, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-0f0c49cc912a083f3'}}], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Attachment': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 22, 21, 33, 44, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-0f35d1842b76cff9a', 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached'}, 'Description': '', 'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': '02:21:d4:20:22:c6', 'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-0e3797492dc4e3299', 'OwnerId': '11000101010', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-30-108.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.30.108', 'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-30-108.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.30.108'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60'}], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'default', 'GroupId': 'sg-40e5492a'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'StateReason': {'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown', 'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'}, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}}], 'OwnerId': 'ReservationId': 'r-05cff59b2524ed79c'}], 

'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'fc80ae94-dd46-4c71-93f5-a38d6ede800c', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type':'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sat, 25 Aug 2018 17:13:51 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

You can note `{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0,` line 2 times in above output and line `'AmiLaunchIndex': 1, 'ImageId': 'ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19'` two times while for the first instance it is `'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-d783a9b8',`  I had created these instances via run_instance method()
as you can see in the print (response) output has come only  but this is not giving a clear picture or I am unable to understand where are three instances in this this is what is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the response object will return one or many Reservation objects.

```
response=ec2.describe_instances()
```

You don't really have to worry about Reservations, other than for the purpose of iterating them. To delve into more detail, you could have a look at this past question,

https://serverfault.com/questions/749118/aws-ec2-what-is-a-reservation-id-exactly-and-what-does-it-represent

So your first block of code is an appropriate way of listing the instance ID's of all EC2 instances.

The second block of code is iterating through the keys in the response object, which is a dictionary,

```
response=ec2.describe_instances()
for x in response:
    print(x)
```

Here's the Boto documentation for the EC2 service, where you can find more info on the response object,

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the followinig error:

```
print(response["Reservations"][2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It states that you're trying to get the 2nd Instance of the Element `Reservations` whihch is not present in the given return.  I would ask you to check the return of the function `response=ec2.describe_instances()` by printing it out on the terminal by using `print(response)` to get familiar with the data_type/return of that function. This will help you get a good grasp of what to expect the next time this function is called.

Also, when you know the kind of return that you're going to get, it will be easy for you to later iterate through the response using something like a `for loop` for lists like elements(which your function, `response=ec2.describe_instances()` returns according to it's documentation.) and then further use the `response` for whatever that you're trying to achieve.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I had used print (response) but I was not able to understand why Reservations[0] has Instance0 but but Response[1] has two members Instance[0] this and Instance[1] this thing has confused me.

Comment: Can you post the output of your `print(response)` for us to have a better understanding?

Comment: I have posted the output of print(response) at the end of question

Comment: as you can see in the print (response)  output has come only for 1 instance

Comment: Just saw your edit, and it doesn't seem to be that fishy, or is it? Your outuput Instances have different number of `AmiLaunchIndex`  have different values but that shouldn't bother you as you can easily iterate through them without having to know the number of instances. Just follow the instructions in the answers and use `for loop` to open and iterate through any list that is being returned

Comment: With the above answer what I understand are there are 2 instances associated with  reservation[1] and 1 instance with reservation[0] that is why `response["Reservations"][2]` is not existing. Is there some way I can programmatically format the out put of response  so that I can understand which bracket goes to which part.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension to get this data.
Example:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  import boto3

  # Creating the boto client
  client = boto3.client('ec2')

  # Get the instance list
  instance_details = client.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
      instance_id,
    ],
  )
  # Get all the Instance details from the Reservations
  # wrapping instances in [] prevents creating a outer list
  [instances] = [x['Instances']for x in instance_details['Reservations']]
```